# Docker port conflict even without binding the port

Tags: docker

I am running 2 Docker containers of a same application without binding to any port, but still getting port is already being used for the second container. Not sure why is this happening as I am not exposing the port.

Running the below command twice with different name.

```
docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock run 
--cpu-shares 512 
--memory 536870912 
-e ARG1=Test
-v /dev/urandom:/dev/random:ro 
-v /tmp/mesos/slaves/f1cb5bcd-0590-40f0-91d6-47fdf0315b19-S1/docker/links/15d651e2-51e8-4c6b-b304-4f7faf5e260b:/mnt/mesos/sandbox 
--net host 
--name test
docker.hub.com/test:latest
```

Comment: `Running the below command twice.` => `--name test`. I would suspect you get a name conflict before you can even get any port conflict.

Comment: Just changed the name. Updating my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Not sure why is this happening as I am not exposing the port.

You are running with `--net host`. You are effectively exposing *all* the ports: that is, the process is running the host's network environment, rather than in an isolated container environment.

If anything else is binding to the ports your containerized application is using (or if you are publishing those ports from another container), you're going to run into this error.

Comment: I am not running anything in that host other than the containers. So, --net publishes port that the container is running.

Comment: Not `--net` by itself, but `--net host`, which means "run these processes in the host network namespace **instead** of isolating them". In most cases you're better off **not** using `--net host` and instead explicitly publishing specific ports.